# How to configure a Gradle application to use SLF4J with a Log4J 2 implementation?

Tags: java, gradle, logging, log4j, slf4j

I'm trying to configure a Gradle project (which uses Lombok annotation processors) to use SLF4J with a Log4j 2 implementation. The project - which was started using `gradle init` and selecting an `application` - has the following structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── classes
│   │   │   └── java
│   │   │       └── main
│   │   │           └── log4j
│   │   │               └── App.class
│   │   ├── generated
│   │   │   └── sources
│   │   │       ├── annotationProcessor
│   │   │       │   └── java
│   │   │       │       └── main
│   │   │       └── headers
│   │   │           └── java
│   │   │               └── main
│   │   └── tmp
│   │       └── compileJava
│   │           └── source-classes-mapping.txt
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── log4j
│       │   │       └── App.java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           │   └── log4j
│           │       └── AppTest.java
│           └── resources
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── log4j2.xml
└── settings.gradle
```

I've put a `log4j2.xml` file in the project directory. According to step 9 in the Automatic Configuration section of https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html,

> If a JSON file cannot be located the XML ConfigurationFactory will try to locate log4j2.xml on the classpath.

My `build.gradle` has the needed dependencies,

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use JCenter for resolving dependencies.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j18-impl:2.14.0'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'log4j.App'
}
```

and the `App` class itself is

```java
package log4j;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Printing a greeting...");
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I run the application using `./gradlew run`, it doesn't print the `log.info()` line,

```
> ./gradlew run

> Task :app:run
Hello World!
```

whereas if I change it to `log.error()`, it does get logged:

```
> ./gradlew run

> Task :app:run
19:26:50.782 [main] ERROR log4j.App - Printing a greeting...
Hello World!
```

Since I've set the level to `trace` in the `log4j2.xml` configuration file,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I would suggest `info`-level logs to get displayed if the configuration file were 'picked up'. This suggest to me that it is not in the class path. I've tried copying it to the `app` directory but to no avail. Where should the `log4j2.xml` configuration file be located to correctly configure Log4J 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `log4j2.xml` to end up on the classpath, the file must be moved to `src/main/resources`. Read more about resources in the official documentation:

- [Building Java & JVM projects: Managing resources](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_resources)
- [The Java Plugin: Project layout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_project_layout)

Comment: I've tried this by creating a `src/main/resources` directory and putting a `log4j2.xml` file in it which contains `log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout` as its first line. I don't notice any change in behavior from that described above, however (i.e., it still doesn't log anything unless I use `log.error()` instead of `log.info()`). It seems like the configuration profile still wasn't 'picked up'?

Comment: It turns out that the `log4j2.xml` configuration file contained syntax of a `log4j.xml` file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320870/log4j2-properties-file-not-picked-up-in-gradle-java-application) so was not interpreted correctly by the new version.